# MongoDB group ISODate but maintain date format

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I know I can group data inside a collection by

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            day: {
                $dayOfMonth: '$timeplay'
            },
            month: {
                $month: '$timeplay'
            },
            year: {
                $year: '$timeplay'
            }
        },
        listeners: {
            $sum: '$count'
        }
    }
```

However, it does not show the date in ISOdate format anymore which is what I need it to still do.

Is there a way to create ISOdate based on this information? As the output currently looks like the following
[image: Current Output]

Comment: You can use [$dateTrunc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$dateFromParts` operator to convert to date from parts,

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateFromParts: {
          day: { $dayOfMonth: "$timeplay" },
          month: { $month: "$timeplay" },
          year: { $year: "$timeplay" }
        }
      },
      listeners: { $sum: '$count' }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i24hx9gI5cp)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$timeplay", unit: "day" } },
         listeners: { $sum: '$count' }
      }
   }
])
```